# JavaScript HTML Injection Error

Tags: javascript, html

I know some of the quirks of injecting HTML via JavaScript are subtle, but this one produces results which don't even make sense. I'm guessing some of the double quote characters are being misinterpreted, but the guides I've read don't seem to suggest doing anything different.

This is a function which injects a series of dynamically labelled buttons into a bootstrap panel and then injects that panel into a row on the page. So far I'm only producing 10 buttons, and I know I need to address the problem of having more than 12 and making a new panel. For now, the button creation is the issue.

```
function tableMaker(data, tableID) {
var panel = '<div class="col-md-12" style="height: 140px"> \n\t<div class="panel panel-default" style="height: 100%"> \n\t\t<div class="panel-heading">Apps Alive</div> \n\t\t <div class="panel-body">';
var mytable       = '';
var colStart      = '<div class="col-md-1"><center><b>';
var titleEnd      = '</b></center>';
var buttonStart   = '<center><button id="';
var buttonMiddle1 = '-appcheck" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg" title="';
var buttonMiddle2 = '" onclick="templateLoader("';
var buttonMiddle3 = '")"';
var buttonEnd     = '-appcheck-icon" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></button></center>';
var colEnd        = '</div>';
var panelEnd      = '\n</div>';


var i = 0, j = 0, colLimit = 12;
for(; i < data.length;){
    for (var j = 0; j < colLimit && i < data.length; ++j, ++i) {
        /*
         * Template
         * <button id="OPS-appcheck" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" title="OPS" onclick="templateLoader("OPS")"><i id="OPS-appcheck-icon" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
         * </button>
         */
        mytable +=  colStart + data[i][2] + titleEnd + '\n' + buttonStart + data[i][2] + buttonMiddle1 +
                    data[i][2] + buttonMiddle2 + data[i][2] + buttonMiddle3 + '><i id="' + data[i][2] +
                    buttonEnd + colEnd;
    }
}

panel += mytable + panelEnd;

document.getElementById(tableID).innerHTML = panel;
}
```

To me, this looks right. Every quote and tag has a matching closer where it should be, but browsers turn the HTML generated into this odd thing:

[image]

The 'type' isn't in remotely the correct spot, and I don't know how it managed to get there based on the string format. There are also a few extra double quotes, but visual inspection doesn't tell me how they got there.

**EDIT** So, escaping the suggested double quotes has produced the following:

[image]

That seems like it should work, but the onclick isn't doing as I'd expect. It's probably a regex issue with my MVC mapping, but maybe it's still the JavaScript.

At the top of the HTML page, jquery.js and then dashboard.js are invoked. At the top of dashboard.js is the following:

```
function templateLoader(appTag) {
    $.get('/app/' + appTag);
}
```

And in the controller for the project (the only one so far), I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generic()
{
    return new ModelAndView("template");
}
```

Yet, if I click any of the buttons, I get no reported request according to the Tomcat logs, and I'm not being redirected to my target page. Is it the mvc, or the script? There are no errors in the dev tools console either.

Comment: `For now, the button creation is the issue` - in what way? what do you expect, what do you see instead

Comment: Sorry, I keep hitting enter when doing the tags. It's been edited and completed. Refresh :)

Comment: the problem is with the double quotes here - `templateLoader("'` and here `var buttonMiddle3 = '")` ... change those two only to \'

Comment: Thanks for that! There's one more tiny quirk if you have the time. See the edits.

Comment: @patrickjp93 If you stick a breakpoint (using chrome debugger) in templateLoader function, you can determine if it is actually being called or not

Comment: change `$.get('/app/' + appTag);` to `console.log(appTag)` just to see if the function is being called

Comment: It does get there, so that means I'm not serving the return data correctly, as if I add /app/OPS to the end of my base url in the search bar, I get put on page I want. And I did confirm "OPS" is being brought in as the appTag, so all the calls are right, but there's more I need to do with the $get(...) part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log(panel)` at the end of your function, it becomes very clear

change these two vars

```
var buttonMiddle2 = '" onclick="templateLoader(\'';
var buttonMiddle3 = '\')"';
```

Comment: See the new edits. That has fixed the main issue, but the onclick function isn't functioning.

Comment: Nope, hence the quirkiness. ;)